# SQLite SELECT LIKE query with forward slash

Tags: sqlite

In my database I'm storing timestamps in a TIMESTAMP field, the table structure is: (It would be difficult to change it to an int storing something like a unix epoch instead at this point)

```
CREATE TABLE timer (
    [id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    [topic] VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    [desc] VARCHAR(500)  NULL,
    [project] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    [start] TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    [end] TIMESTAMP NULL,
    [user] INTEGER  NOT NULL
)
```

Now I need to select rows where the start date is in a certain month. I thought I could just do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM timer WHERE start LIKE "%month/%/year%"
```

But it's not working. But if I just do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM timer WHERE start LIKE "%8%"
```

It runs and selects all the rows with a start date in August (as well as ones with 8 in the time hehe)

I tried narrowing the issue down to:

```
SELECT * FROM timer WHERE start LIKE "%/%"
```

And found that the query returns absolutely nothing if the like string contains a forward slash `/`. I tried escaping the slash but that didn't change anything.

Why is my query not working when I include forward slashes?

Here is some sample data from the table:

```
id  topic     desc        project  start                   end                     user
1    Topic 1   A Desc.     1        8/12/2016 11:34:09 PM   8/12/2016 11:34:15 PM   1
2    Topic 2   A 2ndDesc.  1        8/13/2016 12:55:44 AM   8/13/2016 12:55:49 AM   1
```

EDIT:

As requested, here is an INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO timer (`topic`, `project`, `desc`, `start`, `end`, `user`) VALUES ('My Topic', '1', 'This is a Desc', '2016-08-15 10:03:41', '2016-08-16 12:03:41', '1')
```

Comment: Could you provide an INSERT example? And what client are you using?

Comment: @cartant I don't understand how an insert example is relevant to the question? For the client I'm using SQLite Administrator http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/ :)

Comment: It matters because you can shove anything you like into a column in SQLite unless you have written your own triggers to enforce type constraints. Anyway, I've answered the question.

Comment: I fixed a bunch of errors in the answer - it's early and pre-coffee, here. It can sometimes be useful to look at the database with another tool. The one I use is [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/products/sqlitespy/index).

Comment: @cartant ah I see, I added an INSERT into the main post, and now I'm looking at your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite's `TIMESTAMP` type stores dates/times as [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings (there is [no fundamental `TIMESTAMP` type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#section_2) in SQLite) like this:

```
2016-08-14 21:00:42
```

Which does not contain a slash. The data is likely being reformatted when you are presenting it.

SQLite doesn't constrain data types, so it's possible that you could be inserting non-ISO8601 strings. It depends upon your SQLite library and upon your `INSERT` statements. However, your `start` column is defined as `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so default values for `start` **will be** ISO8601 strings. If you don't have consistently formatted times, you won't be able to query the data.

The ISO8601 format is sortable, so the `SELECT` you want to perform can be made more efficient:

```
SELECT * FROM timer WHERE start >= :from AND start < :to
```

Note that single-digit months in `:from` and `:to` would need to be left-padded with a zero. And note that the month in `:to` does not have to be a valid month. This would work:

```
SELECT * FROM timer WHERE start >= '2015-12' AND start < '2015-13'
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining about the TIMESTAMP type, I knew there wasn't really a TIMESTAMP type for SQLite and as I couldn't find a page on it anywhere I was curious as to how it was working :)

Comment: I opened the same database in SQLiteSpy, and sure enough the date separators show as dashes. I re-ran my query with dashes instead of slashes, and with the year and month in the correct order and it worked as it should. 

Thanks for the SELECT example, It works perfect! I haven't had to work much with dates and times in SQL databases before, so this is a bit of a learning experience for me :)